# python requestsモジュールで空ファイルをアップロードすると、リクエストヘッダに`Transfer-Encoding`が追加されます。なぜ追加されるのでしょうか？

Tags: python, python-requests

## 環境

- python 3.8
- requests 2.24.0

## やりたいこと

pythonの[requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/)モジュールでファイルをアップロードしたいです。

## 質問

空ファイルをStreaming Uploadすると、リクエストヘッダに`{'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}`という情報が追加されます。
なぜ`Transfer-Encoding`がリクエストヘッダに追加されるのでしょうか？
また、空ファイルをStreaming Uploadする際、`Transfer-Encoding`を追加しないようにするは、どのような設定をすればよいでしょうか？

## 試したこと

### ファイルの種類

- `empty.txt`: 空ファイル（0byte）
- `foo.txt`: `foo`という文字のみのファイル（3byte）

### Streaming Upload

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads

```
def upload_streaming(file):
    with open(file, mode="rb") as f:
        r = requests.put("https://httpbin.org/put", data=f)
        print(r.request.headers)

upload_streaming("foo.txt")
# {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '3'}

upload_streaming("empty.txt")
# {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
```

### File Upload

```
def upload_file(file):
    r = requests.put("https://httpbin.org/put", data=file)
    print(r.request.headers)

upload_file("foo.txt")
# {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '7'}

upload_file("empty.txt")
# {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '9'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

> なぜTransfer-Encodingがリクエストヘッダに追加されるのでしょうか？

以下のような処理だったから。

```
        if is_stream:
            try:
                length = super_len(data)
            except (TypeError, AttributeError, UnsupportedOperation):
                length = None

            body = data

            # 省略

            if length:
                self.headers['Content-Length'] = builtin_str(length)
            else:
                self.headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
```

https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/8149e9fe54c36951290f198e90d83c8a0498289c/requests/models.py#L500

> また、空ファイルをStreaming Uploadする際、Transfer-Encodingを追加しないようにするは、どのような設定をすればよいでしょうか？

`requests.put`メソッドの`headers`引数でコントロールする